# Unable to trigger event on S3 object created by Kinesis Firehose delivery stream

Tags: asp.net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I had created kinesis firehose delivery stream which store response file into s3 bucket but i'm not able to trigger event on s3 bucket when file get store or put inside bucket using kinesis.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. What do you mean by "not able to trigger event on s3 bucket"? What are you doing and what error/problem are you experiencing? Please Edit your question to add more details.

Comment: I am also in a similar situation. I have a Kinesis Firehose that pumps data to redshift. I want to use s3 create trigger on the same files to trigger a lambda. When I manually upload a file, the trigger works. But the trigger does not work when Kinesis Firehose creates the files

Answer (score 0):

[link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html)

> New object created events — Amazon S3 supports multiple APIs to create objects. You can request notification when only a specific API is used (for example, s3:ObjectCreated:Put), or you can use a wildcard (for example, s3:ObjectCreated:*) to request notification when an object is created regardless of the API used.

Try creating event for "All object create events" if you didn't already. Usually desired behavior, also works with firehose generated files